# How to fix a bent earphone jack

Tags: technology

How can I fix this kind of bent earphone jack? It still works if I constantly push it in, but it won't work if I don't push it, because it doesn't really fit inside anymore...

[image: the bented earphone jack]

Comment: Its a problem because of covid 19....

Comment: So how can i do it myself? I have tools

Answer (score 4):

The best hack is a proper replacement. An electronics repair shop can do it for you in just a few minutes.

If you insist using the broken connector, you risk damaging the electronics in which you plug it, by creating some short-circuit.

Comment: You also risk the loose part of the jack breaking off completely and getting stuck in the port.

Comment: That's not how this works: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/65079/227085

Comment: @SurpriseDog: if the equipment is designed properly (you know, the part with "dc blocking capacitors and series resistors"), then there is no much risk. But there are devices, and branded, which skip every component which is not strictly mandatory for the basic function. I would not risk destroying any equipment just to save a few cents / dollars - the cost of replacing the connector. Not to mention, as @ Hobbes said, that part of the connector can remain stuck in the device after it breaks completely.

Answer (score 4):

You get a pair of pliers and slowly and carefully bend it back straight. You then put the pliers down, grasp the plug in two hands and try to pull it apart with your fingers (try to break it using the same forces it will be subject to in-service). Pull at least twice as hard as you'd pull to get the plug out of the socket

At this point one of two things will be the case:

The internals of the plug are secure and aligned enough that they work. You aren't able to pull them apart; it'll be fine until you can get around to replacing it.

The internals of the plug are weakened or break off while you're bending it back or pull testing it  - it was a goner anyway and now you can definitely know you need to replace it (and you don't have to pick it out of the socket of the phone :) )

<sub>ps; quick note on terminology here: strictly speaking the jack is the socket into which the plug goes but people do variably use jack to mean either side of this (jack being a contraction of jack plug), so I've deliberately used plug and socket for clarity</sub>

Comment: Note that it has to be fairly accurately straight. A slight bend can already lead to intermittent or no contact, depending on the socket (leading to the 'it only works when I hold it exactly like this' problem). Also make sure the pliers don't put dents in the plug material, that will also lead to contact problems.